# How to solve this error on Devise on ruby 2.2.4, Rails 4.2.5.1, and gem version 2.4.5.1: cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried all the solution that I can find in here but no one has worked for me yet. I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: which version of bcrypt is in your gem file? and whats the ruby version?

Comment: I don't have a bcrypt in my gem file. My ruby version is 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Update bcrypt version to 3.1.9

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.8'
```

Try these git-hub links. These may come handy to you.

https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/102

https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/128

Comment: After I bundle install this, and I restart my rails server, it won't run anymore because it gives me an error. I tried other bcrypt version but still the same result.